# What level of access to Salesforce backend the client could provide a developer?

Tags: administration, page-layout, form

I am a web developer and not familiar with Salesforce at all.

In a web project, I have been required to implement a donation form with a fairly complicated UI. What I am given tho is a URL that they call it API and I am supposed to use it as an **IFRAME**.

```
<iframe src="https://api.causeview.com/form/v2.1/a0JC0200230lBfc7NAC"></iframe>
```

The style and position of elements in the provided IFRAME is pretty basic and I need to be able to inject some **CSS** and **JavaScript** and maybe modify the **template**. Ideally, something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my own style" />
<script src="my own javascript"></script>
<div class="my-template">
    {{form-personal-info}}
    {{form-payment}}
</div>
```

The problem is I have no idea how forms are generated in Salesforce and if the Salesforce administration panel allows the client to give me access to the form **layout editor** (or whatever it is called).

My question is that what should I specifically ask the client to provide me so I could modify the form layout and inject my own styles ans scripts?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. Are you supposed to port the "api" URL into Salesforce or edit it where it is? If the former, you need to get yourself some Visualforce help. If the latter, why not edit it directly at its source instead of in Salesforce?

Comment: @SebastianKessel I have to make the content of the iFrame look like the design. But it is not possible to use JavaScript to manipulate the iframe. That's why I want to know how I could edit the form and styles and script I need.

Comment: My recommendation is to update the iframe's code directly instead of trying to add the CSS to whatever Salesforce wrapper you build. I'm no CSS expert but I don't know if you can affect the content of an iframe from outside the iframe

Comment: @SebastianKessel thanks, I think so too. What should I do to update the code directly? Is there such a thing in Salesforce that you could allow a developer modify layouts without giving them full access to your account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Causeview is a third-party product built on top of the Salesforce platform to handle donation processing, and (as you can guess from the URI you are IFRAME-ing) their forms are not actually generated by Salesforce. The admin of the organization using Causeview will have created the form in the ActionPage Designer (inside of Salesforce).

They have the ability to adjust the form within some parameters, but it does look like it'd be trivial to add some form specific styles. You can read more about how to do this in the Causeview documentation: https://help.causeview.com/aspx/ArticlesByTopic?topic=Actionpages%3a+Online+Forms.

They should also have the option of generating a "code snippet" to use the form on your site, or so the docs have led me to believe.

To answer your final and big question - you should schedule a meeting with your client where they show you the ActionPage Designer and you work with their Salesforce admin to make the necessary changes.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is there is an agency in the middle and it will take forever if I want to wait for a meeting, I want to come with a simple clear request from the client. Your answer gave me a very good clue of what is what!

Comment: @alexar - good luck! Causeview has fairly responsive support too, so reaching out to them for additional docs might help.